How do I get Speech recognition permissions in an iOS WebView?
I'm trying to apply Speech Recognition permissions within a React Native WebView.
I have granted microphone and speech recognition permissions to my app using react native-permissions.
I have also set the NSMicrophoneUsageDescription and NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription permissions in the info.plist file of the project's iOS folder.
While an alert appears to request permissions on Android when there are no permissions, nothing happens in the iOS WebView.
How can I obtain Speech recognition permissions within the iOS WebView?

ios version : 17.2
webView userAgent info : Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 17_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148

this is simpified source code.
import React, { useRef } from "react"
import { initialWindowMetrics, SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context"
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text} from "react-native"
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';

const  App = ()  => {
  const webViewRef = useRef<WebView>(null);

  const recogStart = () => {
    webViewRef.current?.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ type: 'start'}))
  }

  /** simplified code */
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider initialMetrics={initialWindowMetrics}>
      <View style={{alignItems: "center", justifyContent:"center", flex:1}}>
        <WebView
          ref={webViewRef}
          originWhitelist={['*']}
          containerStyle={{width: 100, height: 100, alignItems:"center"}}
          webviewDebuggingEnabled={true}
          source={{ html: `
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
              <head><meta charset="UTF-8" /><title>Speech Recognition Script</title>
              </head>
              <body>
                <script>
                  let recognition;

                  window.SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
                  window.SpeechRecognitionEvent = window.SpeechRecognitionEvent || window.webkitSpeechRecognitionEvent;
            
                  if ("SpeechRecognition" in window) {
                    recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
                    recognition.interimResults = true; // Get interim results
            
                    recognition.addEventListener("start", (event) => {
                      console.log(event);
                    });
            
                    recognition.addEventListener("error", (event) => {
                      console.log(event);
                    });
                  } 

                  const rnMessageListener = (msg) => {
                    const data = JSON.parse(msg.data);
                    
                    if(data.type === "start") {
                      recognition.start();
                    }
                  };

                  /** android */
                  document.addEventListener("message", rnMessageListener);
                  /** ios */
                  window.addEventListener("message", rnMessageListener);
                </script>
              </body>
            </html>`
          }}
        />
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
          <TouchableOpacity 
            style={{ backgroundColor: "blue", height: 50, width: 200, alignItems:"center", justifyContent:"center", borderRadius: 20}}
            onPress={recogStart}
          >
            <Text style={{color: "white", fontSize: 20, fontWeight: "600"}}>Start</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  )
};

export default App;

when requested on ios
enter image description here
when requested on android
enter image description here

Could this help?
